# How to change the maximum possible number of open files in SimGrid?

Tags: simgrid

This code, for example, open and try to copy one file 1029 times

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1029; ++i) {
    MSG_process_create("copy", create_copy, data, MSG_host_self());
}
int create_copy(){
    MSG_file_rcopy(file, src, argv[2]);
}
```

I have exception:

```
[dave:copy:(1027) 0.034653] simgrid-master/src/xbt/exception.cpp:45: [xbt_exception/CRITICAL] Uncaught exception xbt_ex by copy/1027: Too much files are opened! Some have to be closed.
```

Is it possible to change the maximum number of simultaneously opened files? Or this restrictions of my RAM memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there was a hardcoded limit to 1024 files/host, I've just added the storage/max_file_descriptors flag to allow changing this value ( --cfg=storage/max_file_descriptors:2048  to set it to 2048).
The commit (c52c503d21e5) is on the gforge and was not yet propagated to github, this should be done soon.

Comment: It should be OK on the github, now (untested, though).